# Error 1064 when using Insert in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to insert some data into a table for a project, and no matter what I do I'm getting an error. The table is this:

```
    CREATE TABLE StuSchedule (
    StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    1Class VARCHAR (3),
    1Class VARCHAR (3),
    1Class VARCHAR (3),
    1Class VARCHAR (3),
    1Class VARCHAR (3),
    1Class VARCHAR (3)
);
```

and then when i try to insert with

```
INSERT INTO StuSchedule (
    StudentID,
    1Class,
    2Class,
    3Class,
    4Class,
    5Class,
    6Class,

)
VALUES
    (
        12345,
        '100',
        '251',
        '302',
        '111',
        '121',
        '300'
    ),
    (
        54321,
        '251',
        '111',
        '100',
        '300',
        '121',
        '302'
    );
```

It doesn't work. Someone help a newbie out lol

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please also paste the error you get? Did you try to google the error and find an answer yourself?

Comment: You have too many `,`

Answer (score 0):

First :

```
CREATE TABLE StuSchedule (
    StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    1Class VARCHAR (3), 
    1Class VARCHAR (3),-- should be 2Class
    1Class VARCHAR (3),-- should be 3Class
    1Class VARCHAR (3),-- and so on..
    1Class VARCHAR (3),
    1Class VARCHAR (3)
);
```

Second :

```
 INSERT INTO StuSchedule (
        StudentID,
        1Class,
        2Class,
        3Class,
        4Class,
        5Class,
        6Class -- remove ","

    )
.....
```

Comment: The repeating numbers was a typo, but the second one fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you did indeed use that exact create statement, then all your columns are named "1Class"

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore your possible 1Class copy paste typo.

You should set your StudentID primary key to be auto incremented, and then do the insert statement without the StudentID column mentioned, the ids will be generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you have the same column name six times, you gonna have to change your create query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE StuSchedule(
    StudentID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    1Class varchar(3), 
    2Class varchar(3), 
    3Class varchar(3), 
    4Class varchar(3),
    5Class varchar(3), 
    6Class varchar(3));
```

Just for an advice, it's not a good practice to have column names start with a number. Some databases may not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Extra comma problem.
Use this query :-

```
INSERT INTO StuSchedule (StudentID, 1Class, 2Class, 3Class, 4Class, 5Class, 6Class) 
   VALUES (12345, '100', '251', '302', '111', '121', '300'),
          (54321, '251', '111', '100', '300', '121', '302');
```